# Low quality/needs editing/needs moderation 'hitlists'

Tags: discussion, search, quality-evaluation

In order for our community to effectively find posts which need work done on them to improve their quality, I think we should all share our favourite 'hitlists' for posts which may require:

- closing
- editing
- updating
- deleting
- general guidance

These 'hitlists' generally take the form of specialised search queries.

**Please add your 'hitlists' in the answers below so we can find posts which need work done on them and improve them.**

Comment: I probably should have checked if this was OK in chat before posting - if you think this should be deleted, let me know

Comment: In general, if you have a specific issue that you would like to draw attention to that's fine, but going searching for things to fix isn't a good use of time.

Answer (score 2):

[terraria](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terraria)

When the old official wiki (hosted on the Terraria Online forums) was migrated to the new official wiki site (Gamepedia), all old page links were set to redirect to the *homepage* of the new wiki, rather than the correct page on the new wiki. As such there are many outdated links laying around on our site which only point to the homepage of the new wiki.

[Link to hitlist](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=[terraria]%20url%3A%22wiki.terrariaonline.com%22)

**Search terms:**

```
[terraria] url:"wiki.terrariaonline.com"
```

Comment: Note that this is just a very specific example, other hitlists can be much broader.

Comment: These answers are not "low-quality", all they need is an update. That does not make them bad. Assuming they have summarized what was behind the link in the first place.

Comment: @Arperum I know they aren't low-quality, they just need work done. Maybe I should re-word the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if I understand this meta properly (and also kinda on the fence as to whether it's needed), but nevertheless one particular tag that I tend to check up on semi-regularly is:

[xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox)

[xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox) is meant for the original Xbox, however as a term, 'Xbox' is generally used interchangeably to represent any of the Xbox line of consoles, so sometimes users will tag with [xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox) when they mean [xbox-360](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-360) or [xbox-one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-one).

We're usually pretty good at spotting this as it happens though sometimes they can go unnoticed, especially if we get a large influx of questions all at once (such as around a major release of a game).

The action would therefore to ensure the [xbox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox) tag is being applied correctly and correct it when it is not.*

<sub>* and also fixing anything else wrong with the post while you're there, like spelling, formatting & grammar :-)</sub>